# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]' using C#

Tags: c#, hashcode, gethashcode, imageurl

For my project I need to get the Image sourse as hash code like this 28F996F0.jpg. I am trying the following code to get this value but having one error-Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte[]'.

```
 var Image= ImgresponseJson.query.pages[ImgfirstKey].thumbnail.source;
 img.ImageData = string.Format("{0:X}.jpg", Image.GetHashCode());
```

My Json object class is

```
public class PoiImageAnswer
{
 public int Width { set; get; }
 public int Height { set; get; }
 public byte[] ImageData { set; get; }
}
```

I could not get how to convert the image url to hash code like this  28F996F0.jpg

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what the problem is.. you are trying to set `ImageData which is of type byte` to a `string` also they proper syntax is `public int Width { get; set; }`

Comment: `Encoding.GetBytes` creates a byte array from a string... but I'm not 100% sure, that's what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Hash
{
    public static string GetHash(string input)
    {
        HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] byteHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);
    }
}
```

Is it what your looking for ?

Comment: I want to it directly in my code. Like I extract the image source in this line var Image= ImgresponseJson.query.pages[ImgfirstKey].thumbnail.source;. so basically this is the url .then in the next Line I want to do it directly. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a string property to your PoiImageAnswer class to contain the image url. e.g.

```
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
img.ImageUrl = string.Format("{0:X}.jpg", Image.GetHashCode());
```

EDIT:

This would allow you to put it into the byte[]:

```
img.ImageData = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(string.Format("{0:X}.jpg", Image.GetHashCode()));
```

Comment: Thank you it is working. as ImageUrl is in string format. But if I want to keep it in  byte format like my code  byte[] ImageData { set; get; } is it possible anyway.

Comment: it shows error 'System.Text.Encoding.UTF8' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put in the ().

Comment: @Kelvin I tried this one. this shows the output "ImageData": "QzgyRTRENjguanBn". BUt can I get 28F996F0.jpg this type of number from this code.

Comment: How are you trying to get the string back out? You'll have to reverse the process e.g. var testString = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(img.ImageData)

Answer (score 0):

simply modify the last class property:

```
public class PoiImageAnswer
{
 public int Width { set; get; }
 public int Height { set; get; }
 public string ImageDataFilename { set; get; }
}
```

then your code will work:

```
string ImageURL = "http://kajsdkajdg.com/abc.jpg";
var ImageURLHash = string.Format("{0:X}.jpg", ImageURL.GetHashCode());
```